# Unable to copy some element of one list to others

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have list contains some data with zero and nonzero entries. Now i want to filter out nonzero entries from `entries` list.For the purpose i have created anothe list called  `nonZeroEntries`.

```
private List<FinancialReport> entries;
private List<FinancialReport> nonZeroEntries;

entries = this.financialReportDao.getAllLedger(ledgerName);
// now entries list have 26 entries with zero and nonzero.

for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
            FinancialReport entry = this.entries.get(i);
            if((entry.getCredit()!=entry.getDebit()) )
            {   
             nonZeroEntries.add(entry);
             // it shows error here.
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Geez, I don't know, maybe a NPE

Comment: what error you are getting? You said you want to filter out non zero entries but in `if` you are checking for debit!=credit. Doesn't make much sense to me?

Comment: @Helios see funny positioning of `!`

Comment: it shows null pointer exception

Comment: @ScaryWombat yeah it took me sometime to get the condition right. It doesn't help code to be readable.

Comment: @scary Wombat it did't work in my case again.

Comment: @Helios in case both value are ==0.0 i.e credit and debit . I want to filter such entries.

Comment: @PritamTiwari in that case your condition should be `if(entry.getCredit()==0 && entry.getDebit()==0)`. Now if your credit is 5 and debit is 10, still your condition is getting satisfied though those are non zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have

```
private List<FinancialReport> nonZeroEntries=null;
```

you can not add stuff to it.  So you need

```
private List<FinancialReport> nonZeroEntries=new ArrayList<FinancialReport>();
```

Also it would be easier to read as

```
if(entry.getCredit() != entry.getDebit())
```

Comment: i tried private List<FinancialReport> nonZeroEntries; also. But didnt works

Comment: @PritamTiwari Have you heard of something called a _constructor_ ?

Comment: @PritamTiwari You need to instantiate nonZeroEntries.  See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

please check you code, the variable nonZeroEntries is null,before add an element to it,you should do like this:

```
nonZeroEntries = new ArrayList<FinancialReport>();
```